# Run Securom via Proxy

Tags: proxy, drm

I just installed a game which requires a 'release date check', the problem is I access the internet via a proxy and the 'release date check' always fails. Is there any way to make a specific program connect to the internet via proxy? The Proxy add is localhost and port is 6050.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there are tools like
[Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) and
[WideCap](http://widecap.com/)
which tunnel all your traffic through a http or socks proxy

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could hack this is if the program uses a DNS host for the remote host and not an IP address (which is a good bet).  You'd need to install a name server that resolved the host in question (or use a hosts file) and have the substitute host do the proxy.